# Sortable Categories on per Entry basis

Tags: categories, ordering

I've been searching all over for this and have been coming up short unfortunately. Does anyone know if it's possible with in Craft CMS 3 to allow custom sorting of categories on a per entry basis?

For instance, maybe one entry is:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3
- Category 4

And on another entry, the admin orders the categories as:

- Category 3
- Category 4
- Category 2
- Category 1

If not available in Craft's core functionality, does anyone know of a custom category field type that allows this?

Thank you!

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible using Craft's Categories since Categories are a hierarchical structure and will always keep the order they are set in the Category Group when they are added to a category field.

One way around this limitation is to use a channel of entries in place of categories, since it is possible to drag and drop the order of related entries in an entries field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Steve. Appreciate the work around as well!